# list python-dev as install_requires in setup.py

Tags: python, lxml, setup.py

Is there a way to tell python in the setup.py file that "python-dev" (which cannot be installed with pip because is a OS package) is necessary and therefore should be installed?

How to install it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

No.  For one thing, the `python-dev` package is specific to Debian-like distributions; there is no guarantee that other distributions will have a package with the same name that fulfills the desired role.  For another, the user installing your Python package may have permission to install Python modules (e.g., in a virtualenv or user-specific directory) but not permission to install system packages.