# Which exception for a missing external dependency?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, dependency-management

I have read that for [good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702938/list-python-dev-as-install-requires-in-setup-py), it's not possible to let `pip` resolve external dependencies (e.g. that are not available from PyPI).

My project requires two of them, so it should certainly check at startup if these dependencies are installed. If not, I would like to raise an exception, but is there anything standard for this situation? It doesn't look like an `OSError`, nor `IOError`. A `RuntimeError` looks a bit too general. Would an `EnvironmentError` be the right one? (It appeared in python 3.3, but [the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/exceptions.html#EnvironmentError) doesn't describe it).

I have seen some projects define their own `Missing[External]DependencyError`, but, unless it's possible to argue this *is* the best practice, I would prefer to use a standard one, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is `exceptions.ImportError`

Edit: Sorry, that's Python2, in Python3 it's just `ImportError`, as in

```
raise ImportError('msg')
```

Comment: OK, but are the imports not always related to python libraries? Shouldn't this be a different exception?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You obviously can't import an Exception from a module that doesn't exist (on your system/virtualenv). If you try to import a module you can't import, it raises an ImportError. If you want to raise a "nicer" error for your user to better unterstand, then you should catch it and raise a new ImportError with a more meaninful message or, if you don't want to print a StackTrace to the screen, print someting to stderr.

Comment: `import` statements are always used to import a python library (installed with python or with pip). The external dependencies I'm talking about are not to be imported. So I think raising an `ImportError` is confusing.

Comment: Do you mean like a programm that gets used by your project (like an OCR-Software for example)? (I'd go with an EnvironmentException there, but I'm not certain enough that that's the _best_ choice to have posted it as an answer). I don't think you're talking about an import _you_ don't make, but a module you import makes, which would still be an ImportError. There are modules you can't install with pip, but with apt-get, which then get imported normally. That's why I misunderstood you. Could you maybe give an example of the kind of dependency you mean?

Comment: Well my project makes use of [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html). This is used to validate an xml file against a xsd schema. And of `euktoeps`, what comes from the [eukleides](http://eukleides.org/) package, and is used to compile a specifically formatted text document into an eps picture.